# Burn multiple ERC721 sharing the same trait to mint a new ERC721

Tags: solidity, mint, burn

I have an ERC721 Collection of 5000 NFTs. Some are sharing similar traits in their metadata. I'm looking for guidance to code a burn to mint function that allows holders to burn up to 5 NFT sharing the same traits to mint a new NFT.

How should I approach this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, without the implemented code it'd be impossible to give an answer.

Second you'd have to have the burn function actually implemented in your contract.

=> Burning is not a standard function of ERC721 but an addition.
Guessing that you're using OpenZeppelin implementation
if your contract has a declared burning mechanism you can use it, otherwise since you cannot send to 0 address (require in _transfer) you cannot 'burn' your NFTs.

Lastly, you have to know whether your metadata is onChain or offChain. The two methods would be different.

In conclusion your question is too vague, with too little information and no code, to receive an answer.